# MapKit Ios Adding photo to annotation

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit

I'm writing application for ios and I have a problem. I would like to add a photo to my annotation on `MapKit`.After adding annotation on `AnnotationView`, user has a button that invocates `UIImagePicker`.From this moment I have two problems.

1) How to update image after adding an annotation ?

2) How to add image to annotation? I can add small icon using `leftCalloutAccessoryView` but I would like something bigger. Is there a way to put a bigger image to `AnnotationView`? Or maybe someone knows how to make this small image resize on click?
Thanks for answering.

Comment: For this you require custom annotationview..Try to googling for custom annotation view in map..

Comment: Yes, I actually have custom annotation defined, but have no idea how to add a bigger photo

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351358/swift-custom-mkpointannotation-with-image

Comment: Hey, It was a question asked by me a long time ago when I was still studying. I wasn't even using Swift back then. But thanks Anyway :)